# How is this C++ code working

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on an existing project (written by someone else) and I can't get my head around these two simple functions.

The first function I am interested in contains this:

```
int iCounts[NUM_GRADES];
PROFILEMAN->GetMachineProfile()->GetGrades( pSong, GAMESTATE->GetCurrentStyle()->m_StepsType, iCounts );
```

So I can see that iCounts is passed in to GetGrades, which is fine. But then later on iCounts is used like this:

```
AppendOctal( iCounts[g], 3, foo );
```

So something has changed iCounts. But when I go look at GetGrades, it looks like this:

```
void Profile::GetGrades( const Song* pSong, StepsType st, int iCounts[NUM_GRADES] ) const{
    SongID songID;
    songID.FromSong( pSong );

    memset( iCounts, 0, sizeof(int)*NUM_GRADES );

    ...then some more stuff is done to iCounts

}
```

What I can't understand is, how does the original function's iCounts get modified when in GetGrades there are no pointers involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointers; when you pass one to a function you're not passing a copy of the whole array, but rather a pointer to the array.

Comment: isn't it more like you pass a pointer to the array (actually the first element)? `passing the array itself` sounds confusing/likely to ber misinterpreted to me.

Comment: I don't like that formulation either because it implies int*[] when really you're passing int[]. I prefer to specify that they have pointer semantics (as opposed to value semantics)

Comment: That definitely explains it for me. What is the reasoning behind this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know, that's how it was designed in C. I don't particularly like this behavior, it confuses a lot of people. In C++ I tend to avoid them and stick to std::vector and std::array.

Comment: @CameronBall It was a convenience in C, where it's very common to pass arrays as pointers or (pointer, size) pairs. C++ wanted to be compatible with C to great extent, hence the terrible array semantics. In C++, you always want to use `std::vector<T>` or `std::array<T, N>` instead of `T[N]`.